# Jquery delay or settime out in this

Tags: jquery

On click of a element I'm trying to trigger a number of things, but a couple of them I want delayed until later.. I've tried this with no luck:

```
$('.push').click(function() {
    $('#item1, #item2').addClass('newclass');

    $('.item3, .item4').delay('2000', function () {
        $(this).addClass('hidden'); //Or .hide perhaps?
    });

});
```

.hiden in css is "display: none;" I'm trying to delay hidding item3 and item4 for a couple seconds.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: It doesn't wait 2 (2000) seconds to hide the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.delay()` only affects items in the animation queue; adding a class doesn't put the element into the animation queue. See http://api.jquery.com/delay/.

You'll be better off using the native `setTimeout` method.

```
window.setTimeout(  
    function() {
        $('.item3, .item4').addClass('hidden');
    },  
    2000  
);
```

Comment: I was trying to not use setTime out, or is it ok to use?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it? If jQuery's `.delay()` applied to any element (in the animation queue or not), it would only implement `setTimeout` internally anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by using the following piece of code - http://jsfiddle.net/UzVLk/

```
    $('.item3, .item4').delay(2000).hide('fast');
```

If I hadn't passed any parameter to hide, it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

The signature is `.delay( duration [, queueName] )`

So you can't use a callback `function(){}` as the second parameter. Try this:

```
$('.push').click(function() {
    $('#item1, #item2').addClass('newclass');
    $('.item3, .item4').delay('2000').hide('slow');
});
```